# GPU not showing/not working after power outage

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

I had a short power outage, which resulted in my PC quickly shutting off and then on again, the problem then was that my monitor didn't receive any signal.  I connected the monitor to my motherboard and it works fine. I then checked the device manager and it didn't detect any my GPU, under hidden devices it said this for the GPU:
"Currently, this hardware device is not connected to the computer. (Code 45)

To fix this problem, reconnect this hardware device to the computer."

So I was wondering what I should do, do I reconnect it or install the drivers again or could my GPU been damaged by a power surge?

Answer (score 3):

Power down, re-seat the graphics card, double-check any wiring, power up again.

If still no joy, assume it didn't survive the power surge.

If you live in an area where this type of power outage is common, consider a UPS.

Comment: There is no chance for it to be a software issue?

Comment: Very unlikely… if it was software it may be seen but not function.

Comment: reseated it, and it didn't show up, however i noticed that the fans are still working after i power it up again. Could this lead to another solution?

Comment: https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/has-a-power-surge-killed-my-video-card.1424152/ the best answer in this forum suggested resetting the bios, his gpu's fans were also working, I don't know if i should try it and I don't know what it does. I'm not that known on computers. What do you think?

Comment: I doubt it's an issue with your PC's BIOS. The fact that the device doesn't even show up in device manager is enough evidence for me to conclude that the GPU is fried. Even if the fans are running, it doesn't mean that the card is operational. Fans can run even if the card is dead. I know it hurts to hear you'll have to drop money on a new card, but you should be thankful that it didn't fry more. If surges are common at your home, you may want to invest in a UPS or better surge protector as Tetsujin mentioned.

Comment: Does it inconvenience me to reset it @sam-forbis? (I don't think I've entered the BIOS once since I've gotten the PC) I might as well try everything before I buy a new one.

Comment: It shouldn't cause any issues if you reset it, no. It's worth a try, sure. If your PC uses UEFI BIOS, you can get to it from the "Advanced Startup Options" in Windows 10 (assuming you run that).

Answer (score 0):

I moved mine to another PCIe slot and it thankfully started to work again